# SyntaxError in "ALPHANUM_KEY = lambda s: [int(g) if g.isdigit() else g for g in RE_DIGIT.split(s)]"

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I got the following Python script from http://easybioinfo.free.fr/?q=content/amber-trajectory-gromacs-xtc-conversion

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Workflow based on Trajectory Converter - v1.5 by: Justin Lemkul 
#completely reimplemented and improved by Peter Schmidtke & Jesus Seco

import sys,os,re,fnmatch

if len(sys.argv)>4 :
    f=sys.argv[1]
    if not os.path.exists(f):
        sys.exit(" ERROR : Something you provided does not exist. Breaking up.\n\nUSAGE : python trajconv_peter.py amberCrd amberTop trajDir trajPattern outPutPrefix\n\n \
Example : python amber2xtc.py mdcrd.crd mdcrd.top md *.x.gz md_gromacs\n")
else :
    sys.exit(" \n  USAGE : python amber2xtc.py AMBERCRD AMBERTOP TRAJDIR TRAJPATTERN OUTPUTPREFIX\n\
      Example : python amber2xtc.py mdcrd.crd mdcrd.top md *.x.gz md_gromacs\n\
      Note that the AmberCrd can also be a PDB file.\n")

crd=sys.argv[1]
top=sys.argv[2]
trajdir=sys.argv[3]
pattern=sys.argv[4]
outputPref=sys.argv[5]

traj_files=fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(trajdir),pattern) #get the fpocket output folders


RE_DIGIT = re.compile(r'(\d+)')     #set a pattern to find digits
ALPHANUM_KEY = lambda s: [int(g) if g.isdigit() else g for g in RE_DIGIT.split(s)]      #create on the fly function (lambda) to return numbers in filename strings
traj_files.sort(key=ALPHANUM_KEY)      #sort by these numbers in filenames

print "Will convert the following files : "
print traj_files

csn=1
for file in traj_files :
    ptrajtmp=open("ptraj_tmp.ptr","w")
    print "currently converting "+file
    ptrajtmp.write("trajin "+trajdir+os.sep+file+"\n")
    ptrajtmp.write("reference "+crd+"\n")
    ptrajtmp.write("center ~:WAT,CIO mass origin\n")
    ptrajtmp.write("image origin center :* byres familiar\n")

    ptrajtmp.write("trajout pdb_tmp/mdcrd.pdb pdb")
    ptrajtmp.close()
    if not os.path.exists("pdb_tmp"):
        os.mkdir("pdb_tmp")

    os.system("ptraj "+top +" ptraj_tmp.ptr >& /dev/null")
    if not os.path.exists("xtc_tmp"):
        os.mkdir("xtc_tmp")
    #move to *.pdb
    os.system("cd pdb_tmp; ls *.pdb.* | cut -f3 -d\".\" | awk '{print \"mv mdcrd.pdb.\"$0\" mdcrd_\"$0\".pdb\" }' | sh ; cd ../")   
    pdb_files=fnmatch.filter(os.listdir("pdb_tmp"),"*.pdb")
    pdb_files.sort(key=ALPHANUM_KEY)      #sort by these numbers in filenames   
    if csn==1:
        os.system("editconf -f pdb_tmp/mdcrd_1.pdb -o "+outputPref+"_t1_top.gro >& /dev/null")

    for pdb in pdb_files:
        os.system("echo \"0\" | trjconv -s pdb_tmp/"+pdb+" -f pdb_tmp/"+pdb+" -o xtc_tmp/traj_"+str(csn)+".pdb.xtc -t0 "+str(csn)+" >& /dev/null")
        csn+=1
    if os.path.exists(outputPref+"_traj.xtc"):
        os.system("trjcat -f "+outputPref+"_traj.xtc xtc_tmp/*.pdb.xtc -o "+outputPref+"_traj.xtc >& trajcat.log")
    else :
        os.system("trjcat -f xtc_tmp/*.pdb.xtc -o "+outputPref+"_traj.xtc >& trajcat.log")
    os.system("rm -rf pdb_tmp/*.pdb")

    os.system("rm -rf xtc_tmp/*.xtc")


os.remove("ptraj_tmp.ptr")
os.system("rmdir pdb_tmp")
os.system("rmdir xtc_tmp")
```

But when I run it with:
python amber2xtc.py R_1HHO.md5.pdb R_1HHO.prmtop mdcrd R_1HHO_md*.mdcrd R_1HHO_gromacs

I got the following error:

```
  File "./amber2xtc.py", line 28
    ALPHANUM_KEY = lambda s: [int(g) if g.isdigit() else g for g in RE_DIGIT.split(s)]      #create on the fly function (lambda) to return numbers in filename strings
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The SyntaxError points to "if"

I think it may be an old grammar for Python and was not recognized by current version?

Can anyone help me. Thanks^_^

Comment: What version are you using? It has to be newer than 2.4 for conditional expressions to be supported.

Comment: oh i forgot that on the server it's only 2.4.3. I'll take your suggestion and try it right now @Lev Levitsky

Comment: Well, that's it then. [Conditional expressions were introduced in 2.5](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Conditional expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) have been introduced to Python in version 2.5: [link](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html). They are not supported in 2.4.3, which is what you're running.

One way to work around this is by turning `int(g) if g.isdigit() else g` into a function, and calling that function from the list comprehension.